# Register a module in html template

Tags: angularjs

I have to add a module to a Html template.
eg: "<div my-directive ui-grid-edit></div>"

Now I am creating this directive'myDirective' and want to add ui-edit-grid module to it in the template. As in to add attributes, I can use template.attr('myAttribute','attribute value');
How can I do so for module?

Existing base template:
    GridController.prototype.initTemplate= function($scope,$element,$compile){

```
    var baseTemplate = $element.html('<div id=\"id1\" ui-grid=\"gridOptions\" ></div>').contents();
    $compile(baseTemplate)($scope);
    }
```

Now I want to change the template to :
    GridController.prototype.initTemplate= function($scope,$element,$compile){

```
    var baseTemplate = $element.html('<div id=\"id1\" ui-grid=\"gridOptions\" ui-grid-edit ></div>').contents();
    $compile(baseTemplate)($scope);
    }
```

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what you are asking. Modules don't get added to html

Comment: I have created a custom directive that renders a grid which is readonly. Now I want to reuse the same directive in some other page but with editable grid. For the same grid to be editable I will have to add module 'ui.grid.edit' or you can say enable this feature on the directive. The same can be done as shown in the example above. But how can I enable the feature 'ui-grid-edit' on the template. Hope I cleared my point.

Comment: Not without showing your directive code and explaining what is or isn't working

Comment: This is how I generated my template:-  GridController.prototype.initTemplate= function($scope,$element,$compile){                                        var baseTemplate = $element.html('<div id=\"id1\" ui-grid=\"gridOptions\" ></div>').contents();
  $compile(baseTemplate)($scope);
  }  Now to enable edit option I want the template to be modified to   var baseTemplate = $element.html('<div id=\"id2\" ui-grid=\"gridOptions\" ui-grid-edit></div>').contents();  Now will I add ui-grid-edit to the existing template.

Comment: Code belongs in actual question where it can be formatted and read...not in comment blocks. Edit question with code and proper details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115032/discussion-between-nitin-saxena-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Doesn't explain what the actual problem in changing templates is. Suggest reading [ask]

Comment: If I simply change the template to as mentioned, then compiler takes it ui-grid-edit as an attribute and expects some value to it which in my case I dont have. So cannot edit the template.

Comment: No idea what *"some value to it which in my case I dont have"* means. Is the grid module injected in main app module?